# how to create a new column to unite rows

Tags: r

I want to unite three rows in a column. I can do that however I will use the column as an x axis for the graph but after I united the rows the column becomes a character and when I tried to use as.numeric() it gives me an error. How can I create the new column with three rows as a numeric vector?

```
Day Month Year  Date
1   1     2000  1.02.2000
2   2     2000  2.02.2000
3   3     2000  3.03.2000
```

Like that. Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you add the code which is giving you the error? it will complement your question with some details. And it will enhance your chances to get useful answers.

Comment: Seems you want the column as date and not numeric try `lubridate::dmy(Date)`

Comment: I need to create a graph like cases by date but when I tried to like that the graph does not give me a result. I need a date column which I can use to create my graph

Answer (score 0):

This isn't terribly elegant, but it does get you your dates.

```
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)

df <- tribble(
              ~Day, ~Month, ~Year,
              1,   1,     2000,  
              2,   2,     2000, 
              3,   3,     2000 )

result <- foreach (i = 1:3) %do%
{dmy(paste(map(df,i)$Day,"-",map(df,i)$Month,"-",map(df,i)$Year))}
```

Added after comment below... correct enough in terms of elegance, yet note:

```
tic()
> result <- foreach (i = 1:3) %do%
+   {dmy(paste(map(df,i)$Day,"-",map(df,i)$Month,"-",map(df,i)$Year))}
> 
> toc()
0.02 sec elapsed
> 
> tic()
> mutate(df, Date = as.Date(paste(Year, Month, Day, sep ='-')))
# A tibble: 3 × 4
    Day Month  Year Date      
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
1     1     1  2000 2000-01-01
2     2     2  2000 2000-02-02
3     3     3  2000 2000-03-03
> toc()
0.02 sec elapsed
```

Comment: what on earth are you doing? Why foreach? why multiple maps?? just do `mutate(df, Date = as.Date(paste(Year, Month, Day, sep ='-')))`. Please take time to learn R. Note that R is vectorized in most cases

Comment: Note that your result does not produce a dataframe. it just produces the list. If you want to compare the speeds, then compare your case to `with(df, Date = as.Date(paste(Year, Month, Day, sep ='-')))`